# php mysql shopping cart updating quantity error

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to coding and trying to update quantities in my cart, but it only accepts for one product.

If I add more than one, I can only update the last product, which will also set all the other products to the same quantity.

I need help separating the quantities.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <table align="center" width="700" >
                <tr align="center">
                    <td  colspan="5"><h2>SHOPPING CART</h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <th>Remove</th>
                    <th>Product (s)</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th> Price</th>
                    <th> Total Price</th>
                </tr>

                <?php 

                global $con;
        $total = 0;
        $ip = getIp();


        $sel_price = "select * from cart where  ip_add='$ip'";

        $run_price = mysqli_query($con,$sel_price);

        while($p_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)){

            $pro_id = $p_price['p_id'];

            $pro_price = "select * from products where product_id = '$pro_id'";

            $run_pro_price = mysqli_query($con, $pro_price);

            while($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price)){
                $product_price = array($pp_price['product_price']);

                $product_id = $pp_price['product_id'];
                $product_title = $pp_price['product_title'];
                $product_image = $pp_price['product_image'];

                $single_price = $pp_price['product_price'];

                $values = array_sum($product_price);

                $total += $values;

                ?>
            <tr align = "center">
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value=" <?php  global $con; echo $pro_id; ?>"/></td>
                <td><span style="color: white;"><?php echo $product_title; ?></span>
                <br>
                <img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php  echo $product_image; ?>" width="100px" height="100px"></td>
                <td><input type="number" size="4" name="qty" /></td>
                <?php
                global $con;
                global $Stotal;
                $Stotal = $single_price;

                if(isset($_POST['update_quantity'])){

                    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
                    $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty' ";
                    $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);


                    $Stotal = $single_price * $qty;

                    }




                ?>
                <td><?php echo "KSh. " . $single_price; ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo "KSh. " . $Stotal; ?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php }} ?>
        <tr align="right">
                <td colspan="5"><b>Total:</b> <?php echo "KSh. " . $total; ?></td>      
        </tr>


        <tr align="center">
            <td><input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="update_quantity" value="Update Quantity" /></td>
            <td><button><a href="checkout.php" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"> Checkout </a></button></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    <?php

        global $con;
        $ip = getIp();

        if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

            foreach($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id){

            $delete_pro = "delete from cart where p_id = '$remove_id' and ip_add='$ip'";

            $run_delete = mysqli_query($con, $delete_pro);

            if($run_delete){
                echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";

            }
            }

        }

        if(isset($_POST['continue'])){

        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";

        }


    ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: What product are you calling this on? Whats the content of `cart`? ```$update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty' ";``` Dont you mean to call it onto a product which resides inside `cart`?

Comment: the cart table has the 'p_id' column which gets the product_id from the product table, secondly 'ip_add' that obtains the ip address and lastly the 'qty' that is the quantity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you are naming HTML form controls as 'PHP arrays'. `<input name="remove[]">`

These form element names can only be alphanumeric, and on the server you can differentiate the elements by for instance postfixing the id of the product to the form control name and checking it there.

By the way, I recommend using `$_SESSION` for cart handling

Comment: not quite familiar with sessions,let me try,any advice